# jquery .attr variable use

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the following simple function to open divs with the same name of the grabbed "name" attributes in other divs, any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.div').click(function(){
     var nip = (this).attr("name");
     $('#nip').show()
 })
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: to clarify, the "name" attribute grabbed corresponds to the "id" on other divs that I want to open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this).attr("name")` instead of `(this).attr("name")` to get the name. Then, use `$('#' + nip)` to select the desired element.

Your current selector does not work, because the variable name is contained within quotes, causing `"nip"` to be literally interpreted as `"nip"`.

```
$(function() {
    $('.div').click(function() {
        var nip = $(this).attr('name');
        $('#' + nip).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.div').click(function(){
     var nip = ($this).attr("name");
     $('#' + nip).show();
 })
    });

 </script>
```

You can also use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.div').click(function(){
     var $nip = ($this).attr("name");
     $nip.show();
 })
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you're trying to do, but try this:

```
$("div").click(function(){
 var nip = "#" + $(this).attr("name");
 $(nip).show();
});
```

Also, you should clean up your code a little. Are you actually calling out a class called "div"? Remember to close things properly.